# Wrong JSON view being returned when POSTing to CakePHP API

Tags: ajax, json, cakephp

I've been trying to get [Nodesagencys CakePHP Platform-API-plugin](https://github.com/nodesagency/Platform-API-plugin) working with my Cake app for a few days now unsuccessfully. Could you possibly point me in the right direction?

When I try POST to my `admin_add()` or just `add()` method via jQuerys `$.ajax` I only ever get my `views/$Controller/json/admin_index.ctp` (or `index.ctp`) returned, never the `views/$Controller/json/admin_add.ctp template`.

The request seems to be authenticated ok and is visable in dev tools as a POST (200) but no matter what I do I get the only the index.ctp view returned and NOT the admin_add.

Heres the ajax link:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://dev.mydomain.co.uk/faqArticles.json?token=" + userToken,
    data: data,
    dataType: "json",
```

Heres the admin_add method

```
public function admin_add() {

    // New API code 
    $this->Api->denyPublic('add');

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        if ($this->request->is('api')) {

            if ($this->request->is('json')) {

                // Need to add the current auth'd users to this request data here
                $this->request->data['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

                // Get JSON encoded data submitted to a PUT/POST action
                $data = $this->request->input('json_decode');

                $this->FaqArticle->create();
                if ($this->FaqArticle->save($data)) {

                    // Get the id of the just created post to pass back to client for future updates.
                    $caId = $this->FaqArticle->getInsertID();
                    $success = true;

                } else {

                    $caId = null;
                    $success = false;
                }

                $this->set(compact('success', 'caId'));

            }

        } else {

            // Normal CRUD stuff
            $this->FaqArticle->create();

            // Assigned logged in users to article
            $this->request->data['FaqArticle']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

            if ($this->FaqArticle->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The faq article has been saved', 'flash_success');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('The faq article could not be saved. Please, try again.', 'flash_failure');
            }

        }
    }


    $users = $this->FaqArticle->User->find('list');
    $faqCategories = $this->FaqArticle->FaqCategory->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('users', 'faqCategories'));

    // Set layout
    $this->layout = 'admin';
```

}

views/faqArticles/json/admin_index.ctp looks like:

```
<?php
$this->set('success', true);
$this->set('data', "ADMIN INDEX");
echo json_encode(compact('success', 'data'));
?>
```

views/faqArticles/json/admin_add.ctp looks like:

```
<?php
$this->set('success', true);
$this->set('data', "ADMIN ADD");
echo json_encode(compact('success', 'data'));
?>
```

The responce from every POST is:

```
{
  "success":true,
  "data":"ADMIN INDEX",
...
```

This should return the admin_add JSON view but getting the ADMIN INDEX as per above...

Obviously I'm doing something wrong but what? Any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you make your Ajax request, I think you're simply just linking to the wrong page (the index page instead of admin_add)  I would expect your ajax request to look more like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://dev.mydomain.co.uk/admin/faqArticles/add.json?token=" + userToken,
data: data,
dataType: "json"});
```

Comment: You are indeed right. The cake docs say you should POST to the index - POST /recipes.format RecipesController::add() (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/rest.html#the-simple-setup) but this is obviously not the case with this plugin. Thanks